# Clear Interval issue for a nested setInterval

Tags: javascript, arrays, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to clearInterval an interval that is already set. 
My first setInterval object has a piece of code that does something every 12 seconds, also within the same function, there is another setInterval object that does something every 1 second within this 12 sec timeframe.

So the problem here is, I can do clearInterval for the main (outer) setInterval object, but nothing happens to the inner.

Please refer to the Code snippet.

```
start.addEventListener("click", function() {    

    interval = setInterval(function() {

        Object.assign(h1.style, { color: selectedColor, borderbottom: '4px solid ' + selectedColor });

        interval1 = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);

    }, 12000);

});


stop.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    clearInterval(interval1);
});
```

So, I tried to clear interval the inner setInterval object first and then outer later, still no luck and nothing happens.

Any quick solutions, suggestions are really appreciated as I can't proceed any further with this issue on the way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `interval` and `interval1` variable declaration to a higher scope, so all functions can reach their values.

```
var interval;
var interval1;

start.addEventListener("click", function() {    

    interval = setInterval(function() {

        Object.assign(h1.style, { color: selectedColor, borderbottom: '4px solid ' + selectedColor });

        interval1 = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);

    }, 12000);

});


stop.addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    clearInterval(interval1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interval = setInterval(function() {

    Object.assign(h1.style, { color: selectedColor, borderbottom: '4px solid ' + selectedColor });

    interval1 = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);

}, 12000);
```

Means that you create a new interval and store it at interval1 every 12 seconds. So after one minute, youve got five timers running that will trigger startTimer, interval1 is just pointing to the last one. You may move the interval1 out of interval:

```
 interval = setInterval(function() {

    Object.assign(h1.style, { color: selectedColor, borderbottom: '4px solid ' + selectedColor });

}, 12000);

interval1 = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
```

Or if you really want to kill your browser with tons of intervals, you could store the interval1s in  an array:

```
intervals1=[];
 interval = setInterval(function() {

    Object.assign(h1.style, { color: selectedColor, borderbottom: '4px solid ' + selectedColor });

    intervals1.push(setInterval(startTimer, 1000));

}, 12000);
```

To terminate all intervals:

```
intervals1.forEach(interval=>destroyInterval(interval));
```

Note that its bad style not to declare variables, so you may do:

```
var interval,interval1;
```

in the global scope.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, here is the link to working version of the code : 

https://codepen.io/dev-_-bot/full/YGLoGY/

Comment: @VigneshSharma no i did not: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awvbyb at least the timers are working now. But there are a lot of things to fix...

Comment: @vignwsh sharma youre welcome ;) feel free to hit tje green checkmark or to give an upvote...